# How to know the function name that is running on a POSIX shell script

Tags: sh, posix

I'm trying to figure out if there's a standard way (not a hack that works) to know the name of the function that is being executed currently on a POSIX shell script. I know I can return the name of the script with `$0`. How to apply something similar to functions?

Comment: Would you accept "No, you can't do that in POSIX" as an answer? :)

Comment: If it is right yes. I haven't found any answer yet, so I guess that only a hack can be applied.

Comment: There is no such construction in POSIX shell, but implementation may provide any extension for this (then nothing portable).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A quick search of [the latest POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html) indicates **no**, but:

- The line number `$LINENO` *is* a POSIX feature.
- [You can't get the script name reliably](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/028) (not even from `$0`), because it's not read only and it's not set by some shells.
- You can trace the script using `set -o xtrace`.

Comment: The `$LINENO` variable seems useful. Setting xtrace is too verbose for me in this case. It's very useful in other cases though.

Any reference that backs the second statement?

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: 2.1.6 of the cited document states *The shell executes a function (see Function Definition Command), built-in (see Special Built-In Utilities), executable file, or script, giving the names of the arguments as positional parameters numbered 1 to n, and the name of the command (or in the case of a function within a script, the name of the script) as the positional parameter numbered 0 (see Command Search and Execution).*

Comment: The "name of the command" unfortunately is very vague. The linked article explains this saying "$0 is NOT the answer to your problem. If you think it is, you can either stop reading and write more bugs, or you can accept this and read on." And no, I did not write that :)

Comment: Also, note that `$0` is a shell special parameter, *not* a positional parameter, so it wouldn't be relevant to getting the name of the currently executing *function*. I think calling it a positional parameter in that portion of the standard is an error (although it is correctly stating that it holds the name of the script containing the function, not the name of the function itself).

Comment: @l0b0 I hadn't tought that getting the name from `$0` may not be 100% accurate, so thanks for mentioning that too.

Comment: bash's `exec -a foo bar` runs `bar` with `$0` set to the name `foo` (even if `bar` is a `/bin/sh` script). The fact that that's possible is a pretty clear demonstration re: `$0`'s unreliability. (Any language with an `execv` interface that lets you set `argv[0]` separately from the command to run -- as the underlying C API does -- will have a similar facility).

Comment: Actually, in the **Special Parameters** (2.5.2) section, it does say that `$0` "expands to the name of the shell or shell script".

Comment: @LuisLavaire By default, yes, but the problem is a script can also set its own `$0` value.

Comment: @luislavaire As for `LINENO` "This volume of POSIX.1-2017 specifies the effects of the variable only for systems supporting the User Portability Utilities option." For example `dash` in Ubuntu does not support it.